# typescript access object dynamically

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got this error in typescript

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type
```

when I try to access object property dynamically:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const cities = {
  ny: {
    label: "New York"
  },
  ld: {
    label: "London"
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const [city, setCity] = useState<string>("ny");

  console.log(cities[city].label); //what's wrong here

  return (
    <div className="App">
      hi
    </div>
  );
}
```

any clue how to get rid of such error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that cities have only two keys when you declare it: "ny" and "ld" but then you allow any city to be a key of your cities element.

Changing:

```
useState<string>
```

to

```
useState<"ny" | "ld">("ny")
```

should solve your issue.

If you want to allow more city you could also go with this approach:

```
type City = {
  [key: string]: {
    label: string;
  };
};

const cities: City = {
  ny: {
    label: "New York",
  },
  ld: {
    label: "London",
  },
};
```

and keep your useState.

Finally you could dynamically generate the possible keys based on your cities const using:

```
const [city, setCity] = useState<keyof typeof cities>("ny");
```

Comment: `useState<"ny" | "ld">("ny")`
what if I have a list of array of string, how does it look like here?

Comment: you can then probably use "as const". Check this article.
https://codyarose.com/blog/object-keys-from-array-in-typescript/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `string` type to access properties on your object without index type. But if you use `useState<keyof typeof cities>("ny");` that will pick up that it's not just a string but specific string in an object("ny" and "ld" in this case).

You can also play around with `enum` and index types if you need to :)

Answer (score 0):

`cities` is untyped, and `cities.ny` too, it's literally "implicitly has an 'any' type".
To get rid of this error you should provide type to your variable, for example you can do:

```
interface City {
    label: string
}

const cities: {[name: string]: City} = {
    ny: {
        label: "New York"
    },
    ld: {
        label: "London"
    }
};
```

And compiler will know the type of `label`.